# Boost Spirit placeholder type conversion

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm trying to write a parser that (as a first step, of course it will be expanded a lot) parses a double and creates an object of my class ExpressionTree by passing that double to a factory method of my class.
This was my first try

```
struct operands : qi::grammar<string::iterator, ExpressionTree()> 
{

    operands() : operands::base_type(start) 
    {
        start = qi::double_[qi::_val = ExpressionTree::number(qi::_1)];
    }

    qi::rule<string::iterator, ExpressionTree()> start;

};
```

This doesn't compile (`can't convert from boost::spirit::_1_type to double`) because (if I understand correctly) `qi::_1` is not a double but only evaluates to a double.

I tried using `boost::bind(&ExpressionTree::number, _1)` in any way  but I don't know how I then could get the result assigned to the attribute `_val`

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need lazy actors in the semantic actions.

I'm assuming `number` is a static unary function or a non-static nullary (instead of, e.g. a type):

```
start = qi::double_ [ qi::_val = boost::phoenix::bind(&ExpressionTree::number, qi::_1)];
```

If it were a type:

```
start = qi::double_ [ qi::_val = boost::phoenix::construct<ExpressionTree::number>(qi::_1)];
```

See also

- [Semantic Actions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/semantic_actions.html)
- [Adapting normal functions for Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html)
- [Using polymorphic function objects as "lazy functions" in Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_functions.html)